# Reading the number of lines in a file

Tags: c, linux, file, io

I need to calculate the number of lines in a file , however , I must do that without 
the "easy" functions such as : `fopen` , `fscanf` ,`fgets` ... and so on .

Meaning I can't do this :

```
int calculateLines(char *filename)
 {
     FILE *myFile;
     char c;
     int myLines = 0;

     myFile = fopen(filename, "r");

     if(myFile == NULL)
         return 0;

     while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
         if(c == '\n')
             myLines++;

     fclose(f);

     if(c != '\n')
         myLines++;

     return myLines;
 }
```

For that , I can use only the system calls `read` , `write` , `close` , `open` & `fork`.

From what I've done so far , I think that  :

- open the file with `open`  :  `someResult = wrapper_open(argv[1],O_RDONLY,0);`
- reading line after line with `read` : Can I manipulate read somehow to read line after line ? I've tried to check with its tutorial however came empty handed  .

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be allowed to use `system("wc -l file");`  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really read line-by-line with `read`. Instead, you'd read in a *block* of data (which might contain an arbitrary number of lines, and probably some partial lines). Count the new-line characters in that block, then repeat the read/count process 'til you reach the end of the file.

Comment: But the size of the chunks of data that I read each iteration , how can I decide how much ? just write down a number and proceed  ?

Comment: @ron: Yes, pretty much. Generally, you want something large enough to avoid invoking `read` a huge number of times -- to an extent, the larger it is, the better. At the same time, going tremendously huge (say, gigabytes) would use a lot of memory without accomplishing a lot. I'd probably pick somewhere between 32K and 1 Meg as a starting point, and maybe experiment a bit -- but the exact size probably won't matter a whole lot.

Comment: @ron, each block can be as small as a single character (e.g. `read(fd, &c, 1)`). You can repeat this as long as `read` returns `1` as the number of characters read, and check `c` for a new line character. Once you get something basic like this can work, you can start working on optimizations like increasing the size of the buffer, etc.